# what happened to the *stamp after calling localtime function?

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

- Question: The pointer has not been accessed, but its member's value changed
- Environment

  - Linux distribution(`uname -a`):

  ```
  Linux parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```

  - `gcc -v`:

    ```
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
    ```
  - `cmake`definition set:

    `add_definitions(-std=c11 -g -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -Wall -Wformat=0 -O1 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D_GNU_SOURCE)`
- Detail

  This is stamp struct:

  ```c
  typedef struct _zx_str {
    int len;    // data length
    int size;   // data allocted
    char *data;
  }zx_str;
  ```

  Here is my function:

  ```
  void callfunc() {
    zx_str *stamp = calloc(1, sizeof(zx_str));
    stamp->data = calloc(1, 32+1);
    stamp->len  = 0;
    stamp->size = 33;
    stamp->data[0] = 0;

    zx_time_cur_timestamp(stamp);   
  }

  int zx_time_cur_timestamp(zx_str* restrict stamp, TM_FMT fmt) {

    if (stamp == NULL) {
      goto fail;
    }

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *st;

    // before:*stamp = {len = 0, size = 33, data = 0x55555577bb90 ""}
    st = localtime(&t);
    // after: *stamp = {len = 93824994491248, size = 3, 
    // data = 0x555500544d4c <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x555500544d4c>}


    // ...
  }
  ```
- Efforts:

  1. remove `restrict` keywords
  2. remove `O1` option
  3. replace `localtime` with `localtime_r`
  4. **After I push my code to centos7 server(not virtual machine), it did not happen**

I want to know why it happened and how to fix. Anyone can help me ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you omit the `restrict` keyword?  What does the calling function look like?  Particularly, show how the pointer is declared and used up until the function call.

Comment: I tried, but it's not work

Comment: Where is `stamp` declared and where is the storage allocated? Automatic? Allocated? Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I just edited the code, until calling `localtime`, I did nothing else with `stamp`.

Comment: You need to post how `*stamp` was shown to have changed.  Debugger output is not enough - have code print out the contents  of `*stamp` before and after `st = localtime(&t);`.  Otherwise this assertion `*stamp` is a fiction.  == Other wise, just assume `stamp` was optimized out  after the `localtime()` call.

Comment: If you take that corrupted value for `stamp->len` and convert it to hex, you'll see a bunch of repeating bit sequences.  This is a big hint that you have some memory corruption happening somewhere (likely a buffer overrun somewhere else is writing on top of this code's memory).  The next thing I'd try is removing the `calloc()` calls and using a statically-allocated object instead.  Running your code through valgrind would be a good idea as well.

Comment: @bta I cannot reproduce the error on physical server, so I think maybe it's because I have no enough memory in VM.